# Is there a way to mark an answer in draft status so that the contributor can easily reference it?

Tags: feature-request

I have a question about my WordPress Development Stack Exchange post: [Pull the category name in category.php out of the loop](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/281645/pull-the-category-name-in-category-php-out-of-the-loop/281647#281647)

It would seem that having the ability to mark a question or an answer in draft status would benefit the site considerably.  That way answer authors are able to get complete details about the question from the question authors before being exposed to voting.

Maybe this is already available.  How can it be done (aside from just writing that the answer is a draft in the question text)?

As long as we are on the subject, perhaps a post can also be flagged as needing assistance from someone with greater reputation.  So if new authors need help, they can get the help they need to be encouraged (important for those starting out especially) and productive.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such feature and it would probably overcomplicate things, as well as incentivize wrong behaviors (creating drafts just to "stake" being first to answer and so on).

If you feel your answer is incomplete it is perfectly fine to *use your words* and say so in the body of the answer.

If I am not confident I understand the question completely/correctly I will typically start answer with my understanding of it:

> If I follow you right you want to accomplish X under Y circumstances.
>
> This may be a good starting point in such case...

Comment: Thank you for the positive direction.  If it were something that the author only would see the contribution until it moved out of draft, I do not see any possibility of cheating that system and getting published first.  WordPress itself has this functionality with postmaster plugins. Why not also Wordpress Stackexchange also?

Comment: Notably WPSE doesn't _run_ on WordPress :) The functionality it has is subject to an entirely different platform with different development priorities. So "why not" is probably because it's unimportant and/or unwanted feature in eyes of Stack Exchange development team.